# String Inference Protocol For Generic SwiftUI View

Tags: generics, view, swiftui, protocols, inference

I have come across the question which, if any, protocols exist to specify a generic Type in SwiftUI to be displayed as text in a `Text` view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct GenericTextView<A: DeclarationInQuestion>: View {
    var printableInstance: A
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(printableInstance)")
    }
}

struct GenericTextView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GenericTextView(printableType: Int(1))
    }
}
```

If there is a solution, how will I define and declare `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on whether you're trying to display the passed value, or you're trying trying to display the localized string for the passed key. It looks like you're trying to display the passed value, but your code is calling the initializer for a localization key. You likely want to use `Text(verbatim:)`:

```
struct GenericTextView<A>: View {
    var printableInstance: A

    var body: some View {
        Text(verbatim: "\(printableInstance)")
    }
}
```

That said, I'd avoid writing it that way. There's no reason to re-stringify the value this way. You can just stringify it one time and avoid the generic:

```
struct GenericTextView: View {
    var string: String

    init<Value>(_ value: Value) {
        string = "\(value)"
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(verbatim: string)
    }
}
```

This approach also allows localization keys, just by dropping the `verbatim:`.